# I'm following The Passthrough Post's MacOS tutorial, and I got an error about systemctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macintosh

Is the error I get when Starting the serice:
`Failed to start and.service: Unit and.service not found`

How I start:
`systemctl start libvirtd.service and virtlogd.service`.

I'm Running Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS)64

Comment: This question is not clear: grammar errors, and it is not clear what you are asking. Edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Remove the word `and` from the `systemctl` command. It is not part of the syntax.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.